# How to show $\operatorname{curl}\operatorname{curl}(e_r) = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates, curl

$\DeclareMathOperator{curl}{curl}$I want to figure out how to calculate $\text{curl}(e_r$). Where $e_r$ is a base vector for the Spherical co-ordinate system.

Taking $e_r = (\sin\theta \cos\phi)i+(\sin\theta \sin\phi)j+(\cos\theta)k$

and I tried taking the $\text{curl}(e_r)$ as follows,

$\text{curl }e_r=\begin{vmatrix}i & j & k\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}  \\ (\sin\theta \cos\phi) & (\sin\theta \sin\phi) & (\cos\theta)\end{vmatrix}$

And then took the $\operatorname{curl}$ again for the output of the above. But this gives a non-zero value.
I would like to know whether the above steps and the values I am using for $e_r$ are correct. If not can you please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: $e_r$ is the base vector for spherical coordinate system. Is there is another way I can express $e_r$ ?

Comment: But you provide it as linear combination of Cartesian base vectors, thus in Cartesian coordinates, despite that angles and radius show up. In spherical coordinates it should be simply one times $e_r$, like $e_x$ is $(1,0,0)$. One problem with your attempt is that you mix the versions of $e_r$ and curl, you must use both Cartesion or both spherical.

Comment: So will it be correct if I try to find it as

$\text{curl }e_r=\begin{vmatrix}e_r & re_\theta & r\sin\theta e_\phi\\ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} & \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}  \\ (1) & (0) & (0)\end{vmatrix}$

Comment: Can somebody please explain to me why this question has been closed? "This question is missing context or other details" What is unclear, missing or off-topic?

Comment: @mvw:  While the task of computing $\operatorname{curl} \operatorname{curl}  \mathbf{e}_r$ seems well defined enough, the request to know whether "my approach is correct" seems less well grounded, given the omission of any substantive work to check.  If the OP wants to know whether taking the curl of the curl of a 3D vector field makes sense (or can be accomplished by taking the curl once, and then taking it again), that would be simple enough.  But I'm not sure what "I am not getting the desired result" means above.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopes this makes it more clear and if so please lift the hold on this.

Answer (score 3):

The unit vector $e_r$ is the is nothing but the normalised vector radius:
letting
$$
r=\left(\begin{array}[c]
\ x=\rho\cos\phi\sin\theta\\
y=\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta\\
z=\rho\cos\theta
\end{array}\right)
$$
then
$$
e_r=\frac{r}{|r|},\text{ where }|r|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\rho.
$$
Now, consider $V(r)=|r|$ and compute its gradient
$$
\nabla V(r) =\left(\begin{array}[c]
\ \partial_x|r|\\
\partial_y|r|\\
\partial_z|r|
\end{array}
\right)=
\frac{1}{|r|}\left(\begin{array}[c]
\ x\\
y\\
z
\end{array}
\right)=\frac{r}{|r|}=e_r.
$$
The curl of a gradient is zero, so:
$$
\nabla\times e_{r}=\nabla\times\nabla V(r)=0.
$$

In the comments, the OP asks for some guidance in computing $\nabla \times e_{\theta},$ as well,
where I assume
$$
e_\theta=\left(
\begin{array}[c]
\ \cos\phi \cos\theta\\
\sin\phi \cos\theta\\
-\sin\theta
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Consider the path $\Gamma$ made as follows: for $0<\alpha<\pi/2$ and $\beta$ small, 
start from $(\rho=a,\theta=\alpha,\varphi=0)$ and move to $(a,\alpha+\beta,0)$ along an arc of fixed $\rho=a$, then go to $(a-\varepsilon,\alpha+\beta,0)$ along the radial segment of fixed angles, go back up to $(a-\varepsilon, \alpha,0)$ along the arc of radius $a-\varepsilon$ and finally return to the starting point moving radially. Since $e_\theta$ is a unit vector which is tangential to the above arcs and orthogonal to the above segments, the line integral
$$
\oint_\Gamma e_\theta\cdot dl= \beta\varepsilon;
$$
since, if $\Gamma=\partial \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is the surface enclosed in the path $\Gamma$,
$$
\oint_\Gamma e_\theta\cdot dl = \int_\Sigma (\nabla\times e_{\theta})\cdot da
$$
we conclude that $\nabla\times e_{\theta}\neq0$. Furthermore, since geometrically $\nabla\times e_{\theta}=|\nabla\times e_{\theta}|e_{\phi}$ and the area element of $\Sigma$ is precisely $e_{\phi}\rho d\theta d\rho$, so that
$$
\beta\varepsilon=\int_\Sigma (\nabla\times e_{\theta})\cdot da=\int_\alpha^{\alpha+\beta}d\theta \int_{a-\varepsilon}^a \rho d\rho |\nabla\times e_{\theta}|
$$
and the mean over the surface $\Sigma$ of area $\beta(a^2-(a-\varepsilon)^2)/2$ is given by
$$
\frac{2}{\beta(a^2-(a-\varepsilon)^2)}\beta\varepsilon = \frac{2}{\beta(a^2-(a-\varepsilon)^2)}\int_\alpha^{\alpha+\pi/2}d\theta \int_b^a \rho d\rho |\nabla\times e_{\theta}|.
$$
Letting $\varepsilon,\beta\to0$, the right-hand side approaches $|\nabla\times e_{\theta}|$ computed at $(a,\alpha,0)$ by continuity and hence
$$
|\nabla\times e_{\theta}|=\frac{1}{\rho},
$$
where I have renamed $a=\rho$, to make the expression general, and finally
$$
\nabla\times e_{\theta}=\frac{1}{\rho}e_{\phi}.
$$

Comment: I get it now. Shall I use the same approach i find $\text{curl }e_\theta$ also?

Comment: No: unfortunately $e_\theta$ has nonzero curl if I am not mistaken

Comment: I need to find $curl^2e_\theta$ also. Can you give any suggestions?

Comment: I will edit my answer accordingly, if I succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You provide $e_r$ in Cartesian coordinates, but the second row of your determinant features derivatives for spherical coordinates.

Try again with the second row using a gradient in Cartesian coordinates $\partial/\partial x_i$ or change to a spherical version of the curl, but then formulate $e_r$ in spherical coordinates as well.

**Derivation in Cartesian Coordinates**

In Cartesian coordinates we can write
$$
e_r = r/\lVert r\rVert \\
\partial_i ((e_r)_j) = \partial_i (x_j/\lVert r \rVert)
= (\delta_{ij} \lVert r \rVert - x_j(1/2)(1/\lVert r \rVert)(2x_i))/\lVert r \rVert^2
= \delta_{ij}/\lVert r \rVert - x_i x_j/\lVert r \rVert^3
$$
This gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{curl}{curl}
(\curl e_r)_1 = \{(-x_2 x_3)-(-x_3 x_2)\}/\lVert r \rVert^3 = 0
$$
Only different indices contribute to the curl, so the first term has its Kronecker delta vanish. The second term is symmetric, one can exchange the indices, so this vanishes as well.

The curl of $e_r$ vanishes already, and so would a second application.

**Example in Spherical Coordinates**

The curl operator in spherical coordinates is:

$$
\curl A = 
\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\left({\partial \over \partial \theta} \left( A_\varphi\sin\theta \right)
    - {\partial A_\theta \over \partial \varphi}\right) e_r 
+ \frac 1 r \left({1 \over \sin\theta}{\partial A_r \over \partial \varphi}
    - {\partial \over \partial r} \left( r A_\varphi \right) \right) e_\theta
+ \frac 1 r \left({\partial \over \partial r} \left( r A_\theta \right)
    - {\partial A_r \over \partial \theta}\right) e_\varphi
$$
For $A = e_r$ we have $(A_r, A_\varphi, A_\theta) = (1,0,0)$

This gives $\curl e_r = 0$.

For $A = e_\varphi$ we have $(A_r, A_\varphi, A_\theta) = (0,1,0)$

This gives $\curl e_\varphi = \frac{1}{r}\cot \theta \, e_r - \frac{1}{r} e_\theta$.

For $A = e_\theta$ we have $(A_r, A_\varphi, A_\theta) = (0,0,1)$.

This gives $\curl e_\theta = (1/r) e_\varphi$ and 
$\curl \curl e_\theta = \frac{1}{r \sin \theta}(\partial_\theta((1/r)\sin\theta)e_r $

Comment: but how to show it?